# failing to build python script to .exe with correct conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I've tried using pyinstaller, py2exe and auto-py-to-exe but keep having similar problems. First, py2exe seems to be abandoned, but pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe correctly build an exe that can run, and run the beginning of my code, however when I try to load a pickled model using joblib dump/load I get the following error. This is the same error I get when I run the python script in the wrong environment.

How can I build from the correct conda environment?

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 24, in main
  File "site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 598, in load
  File "site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 526, in _unpickle
  File "pickle.py", line 1088, in load
  File "pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
  File "pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture._gaussian_mixture'
[12708] Failed to execute script test**
```